# Nginx -- if referer, add (x-forwarded-for) ip to blacklist

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have written a basic http referer redirector that looks something like this:

```
if ($http_referer ~* (google|yahoo|bing|duckduckgo)) {  return 301 https://altavista.com; }
```

My goal is something like this

```
if ($http_referer ~* (google|yahoo|bing|duckduckgo)) {
    add $x-forwarded-for bad_ips.txt; <-- this line is the question (x-forwarded-for because it's behind cloudflare)
    return 301 https://altavista.com; 
}
if ($bad_ip) { 
    return 301 https://altavista.com; 
}
```

Is there any way to do this?  The goal is essentially if you are referred from a website on the blacklist, I would like to add your ip to the redirect list.

Note: This does not need to be done purely in nginx; using other technologies in addition to nginx is fine so long as they are free.

Please note my site is utilizing cloudflare so rather than banning a simple IP it has to be using the x-forwarded-for address or I'm just banning cloudflare.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use `fail2ban`? https://easyengine.io/tutorials/nginx/fail2ban/

Comment: I could use fail2ban, but would really like to have it linked to the directive above if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until I remember there is no direct method to do this.

A paid option can be using Nginx Plus according to [this](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/blacklisting-ip-addresses/) blog.

Other than that there are 2 options that I can see now are:

1. Use [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/en/) with LUA module. What you have to do is

   1. on every request write IP to a file
   2. on every request read from the file and if IP exists then 301 redirect.

   If you do not want to use OpenResty then you can also [build Nginx with LUA module](https://techio.dev/nginx/compile-Nginx-with-echo-nginx-module-headers-more-nginx-module-lua-nginx-module.html).

   [I am concerned about efficiency at this point. This method may add performance overhead as the file has to be parsed on every request.]
2. Use Fail2Ban with Nginx.

`I wanted to add this in the comment but I don't have enough reputation to comment.`